# Syntax about chisel :Vec & Wire

Tags: chisel

I am learing Chisel3.

I have some questions about the codes.

```scala
val myVec = Wire(Vec(5, SInt(width = 23)))  // Vector of 5 23-bit signed integers.
```

I thought if I declare a vector and I need to write "Wire",but I was wrong when I saw these codes.

```scala
class BigBundle extends Bundle {


 val myVec = Vec(5, SInt(width = 23))  // Vector of 5 23-bit signed integers.

 val flag  = Bool()
 // Previously defined bundle.

 val f     = new MyFloat

}
```

It punchs on my face suddenly,so I want to know when do I use "Wire"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The key here is the distinction in Chisel3 between "types" and "values."

`Vec`, `Bundle`, `UInt`, `SInt`, and `Bool` are examples of "types."

`Wire`, `Reg`, `Input`, `Output`, and `Mem` are examples of "values."

With `BigBundle` from the above:

```
class BigBundle extends Bundle {
  val myVec = Vec(5, SInt(23.W)) // Vector of 5 23-bit signed integers.
  val flag = Bool()
  val f = new MyFloat // Previously defined bundle.
}
```

`BigBundle` is a "type" just like `Vec(5, SInt(23.W))` is a "type."

If you wish to use these types you can create a `Wire` of one of these types, eg.

```
val myVecWire = Wire(Vec(5, SInt(23.W)))
val myBundleWire = Wire(new BigBundle)
```

EDIT: Updated for modern chisel3 style

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do operation to myBundleWire?It could make me more understand.

Comment: You can access the fields of a Wire (or other value) of type BigBundle using dot notation and connect to them with the connection operator `:=`. Thus if you want to connect the flag field of myBundleWire to false you could write the following:  `myBundleWire.flag := false.B`

Comment: Thanks I totally understood.

Answer (score 4):

You use `Wire` for any Chisel node that you might reassign the value of.

```
val a = Wire(Bool())
a := Bool(false)
...
```